# Como optimizar el código para que se demore menos en correr?

Tags: c++

Estaba resolviendo un problema den OmegaUp, pero mi solución se demora 3 segundos en correr, y el tiempo límite es de 1 segundo. Cómo se podría optimizar el código para que se demore menos? Este es el problema: https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Invirtiendo-segmentos-de-una-mat/#problems

Este es mi código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(){

    
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    int arr[n][n];

    int num = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int e = 0; e < n; e++){
            arr[i][e] = num;
            num++;
        }
    }
    string op;
    while(q--){
        cin >> op;
        if(op == "R"){
            int co, first, last, temp;
            cin >> co >> first >> last;
            for(int i = first; i <= last / 2; i++){
                temp = arr[i][co];
                arr[i][co] = arr[last - i + first][co];
                arr[last - i + first][co] = temp;
            }

        }
        else{
            int b, e;
            cin >> b >> e;
            cout << arr[b][e] << "\n";
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    
    solve();

    return 0;
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sincronización de I/O**

Lo primero que tienes que hacer al afrontar un problema de este tipo de webs con c++ es desincronizar la IO de C++. Todos sabemos que la compatibilidad entre C y C++ es bastante alta. Pues bien, por este motivo y debido a razones históricas C++ viene configurado, por defecto, con las IO propias de C y de C++ sincronizadas.

¿Y esto que implica? Pues básicamente que leer un dato con `cin` es varias veces más lento que hacerlo con `scanf`. La teoría nos dice que no debería ser así, al fín y al cabo:

- Con `cin` se invoca directamente una función que sabe qué es lo que tiene que leer (un entero, un `char`, una cadena ...)
- `scanf` debe interpretar una cadena de texto para determinar qué es lo que tiene que leer en cada momento, y después leer lo que se le haya pedido.

Forzar a que ambos mecanismos estén sincronizados juega en contra de `cin`, ya que tiene que pagar un peaje que aumenta (para lo que se requiere en este tipo de programas) enormemente el tiempo de ejecución.

Lo mejor es desincronizar la IO para evitar pagar peajes innecesarios:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Tras esta llamada será conveniente no mezclar llamadas a `stdin` y a `cin` (por poner un ejemplo), ya que el resultado no será predecible. A cambio, las llamadas a `cin` serán más rápidas que las de `scanf`.

**Ordenar los datos**

Si te fijas, la gracia de este problema está en que realiza operaciones por columnas. Lo ideal entonces sería crear la matriz por columnas en vez de por filas.

¿Y esto por qué?

Tu estás definiendo un array de n*n en la pila del programa:

```
int arr[n][n];
```

Esta estructura se conoce como VLA, o Variable Length Array. No es una característica soportada por el estándar y es conveniente no usarla. Sin embargo en este tipo de programas no se busca lo estándar sino que el programa haga sus cálculos en el menor tiempo posible. Es decir, si el compilador de la web traga con esto y no se desborda la pila, perfecto.

El caso, en un array de este tipo, los datos se organizan en memoria de la siguiente forma:

```
| fila 0 | fila 1 | fila 2 | ... | fila n-1 |
```

y yo te propongo intercambiar filas por columnas:

```
| columa 0 | columna 1 | columna 2 | ... | columna n-1 |
```

Y el motivo tiene que ver por cómo funciona un ordenador por dentro.

Los equipos tienen varios tipos de memoria: Discos, RAM, ... normalmente cuanta más capacidad tiene una memoria más lento suele ser su acceso, esto suele ser así porque las memorias más rápidas suelen ser también más caras.

Hay una memoria especialmente rápida que suele ir junto al micro, es la memoria caché. Esta memoria, con una capacidad de unos pocos megas, es la que le proporciona al micro todos los datos que necesita. Esta memoria está dividida en páginas, de tal forma que para cargar datos que necesita (en una página), es probable que tenga que descartar otros datos. Esta operación se conoce como paginación y, en términos de tiempo, suele ser bastante costosa, por lo que conviene evitarla en la medida de lo posible.

Pues bien, para intentar minimizar los intercambios de página dentro de tu aplicación tienes que intentar que los datos que se utilicen juntos estén cerca unos de otros en cuanto a posiciones de memoria se refiere. Cuanto más alejados estén más probable será que el programa tenga que usar dos o más páginas de caché diferentes solo para realizar la operación.

Dado que el programa hace operaciones únicamente a nivel de columna, lo lógico entonces es organizar los datos por columnas. De esta forma conseguimos que las filas pertenecientes a una columna se encuentren en posiciones contiguas de memoria. Hemos solucionado el problema de la paginación, o no.

Ahora toca rellenar la matriz y, claro, si la sigues rellenando como hasta ahora volverás a tener el problema de la paginación ya que irás saltando de columna en columna... Tienes que recorrer la matriz de forma secuencial, esto es, recorrer primero las columnas y luego las filas. Rellenarla ahora es un poco más complicado, pero solo un poco, una propuesta:

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(arr);
for(int col=0; col<n; col++)
{
    int sig = col+1;
    for(int *end = ptr+n; ptr<end; ptr++)
    {
        *ptr = sig;
        sig += n;
    }
}
```

Ahora no basta simplemente con incrementar un valor, hay que calcular el valor inicial para cada columna. Para cada fila basta por incrementar el valor anterior por `n`.

Y con esto, ahora ya si, hemos solucionado el problema de la paginación. Ahora deberías notar cómo el programa se ejecuta bastante más rápido.

**Evita el uso de string**

Si bien normalmente se recomiendo el uso de `std::string` sobre `char*`, en el caso de este tipo de programas podemos llegar a obviar esta recomendación.

En tu caso es más sencillo todavía ya que ni siquiera tienes que usar `char*`, tu programa solo va a recibir dos órdenes: `P` y `R` estas órdenes te entran en un `char`. Comparar dos `char` es instantáneo, mientras que comparar dos cadenas de caracteres implica al menos la existencia de un bucle:

```
char op;
std::cin >> op;
if( op =='R' )
{
  // ...
```

**Otras mejoras**

Intenta evitar operaciones redundantes. Si necesitas ejecutar varias veces seguidas la misma operación, intenta guardar resultados intermedios para no tener que repetirlos.

Elige con cuidado el compilador. Cada compilador tiene unas características y el binario resultante puede variar bastante. En el caso de C++ suelo tener preferencia por clang sobre g++ ... y preferentemente la última versión disponible, en este caso la que soporta c++17, tendrás que probar cual es el que te da mejores resultados.

Piensa enfoques diferentes. A veces, no tiene por qué ser este el caso, un problema puede ser increíblemente complejo si se afronta desde la perspectiva obvia, a veces es necesario darle un par de vueltas y plantear soluciones diferentes.

En este caso, por ejemplo, podrías optar por no inicializar toda la matriz. Es muy difícil que los casos de prueba toquen absolutamente todas las columnas. Mientras no haya una operación de *swap* , una columna puede quedarse sin inicializar, lo que te ahorrará unos preciosos ciclos de reloj. Es decir, la inicialización de la matriz podría limitarse a algo así:

```
int *data = new int[size*size];

int* ptr = data;
for( int i=0; i<size; i++, ptr += size)
{
    *ptr = 0;
}
```

De esta forma podemos saber si una columna está inicialiada simplemente verificando su primer valor. Si está inicializada nos limitamos a recuperar el valor pedido, pero si no lo está, sacamos el valor que tendría por defecto:

```
int* ptrColumn = data + (column * size);
int cellValue = (*ptrColumn == 0)? (row * size + column + 1) : *(ptr + row);
//                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                    Valor por defecto         Valor real
```

Claro está, cuando nos toque hacer una operación de swap sobre una columna no inicializada, tendremos que darle valores a toda la columna antes de nada.

En el caso de una matriz pequeña, no se notará (e incluso podrías tener alguna penalización), pero en el caso de matrices grandes con pocas operaciones la mejora puede ser abismal.

A modo de prueba, he probado a hacer el ejercicio y he conseguido un tiempo de 0.22 aplicando los cambios que te he dicho. Es fácil ver que ese resultado tiene fecha de hoy. Es probable que se pudiese seguir optimizando, pero como caso práctico creo que es suficiente .

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Me podrías pasar tu código por favor? Recién estoy empezando en c++, y me serviría mucho para aprender. Gracias.